# T-SQL get Cancellation Date of a contract

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I got another SQL question - Working with SQL Server 2016 at the moment:

I've got a Table with detailed-lines for a contract table.

1) The contract-lines have a starting-Date of the contract and a planned end-date. If the customer has agreed a "never-ending" contract, this date is '9999-12-31'

2) There is also a possibility, that the customer has already canceled the contract. The Date of the cancelation can be find at column "Cancelation Date".If the Date is '9999-12-31' the customer hasn't canceled his contract.

3) There are minimum contract durations in the fields "First Performance Period" and "Further Performance Period". Means that the contract has the minumum duration of "Starting Date" +  "First Performance Period" and then expends every time for the duration of "Further Performance Period". The numbers tell the duation of months. (12 = 12 Months)

4) There is a cancelation Period which tells how far in the future the customer can cancel his contract.
Example : If he has a cancelation period of "3" (=months) and wants the contract to be canceled in '2020-01-01' he must cancel it at '2019-10-01'.

--> What I need as a column now is the date, where the customer has the first chance to cancel his contract (or the date where he already canceled the contract). If the contract has already been canceled, it should simply show a bit 0/1 in another column . (sorry for the german Dateformat):

[image]

Here is also some sample data: https://workupload.com/file/6NuVLdtq

Calculation example for the last line of the Screenshot:

```
Starting Date: 01.04.2013
+24 Months = 01.04.2015 (Starting Date + First Performance Period)
+12 Months = 01.04.2016 (minimum duration + further performance period)
+12 Months = 01.04.2017 (+ further performance period)
+12 Months = 01.04.2018 (+ further performance period)
+12 Months = 01.04.2019 (+ further performance period)
+12 Months = 01.04.2020 (+ further performance period)
-3  Months = 01.01.2020 (- Cancelation Period)
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Here is also some sample data: https://workupload.com/file/fyHDM4FP

Comment: What does period mean? Month? Year?

Comment: Its the duration of months the contract will expand or the customer has the chance to cancel his contract

Comment: Aside: You're just asking for trouble when you mix data types in a column like that. You should be adding two columns; a date column with the date you're calculating, and a bit (0/1) or char(1) (y/n) column for `Canceled`.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, added your infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of what you need to do. Basically you need to calculate how many multiples of FurtherPerformancePeriod have elapsed between first performance period and today. Based on this you can calculate next date and next to next date, then choose the next date if there is still time to cancel otherwise choose next to next:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN CancelationDate0 >= Today THEN CancelationDate0
            WHEN CancelationDate1 >= Today THEN CancelationDate1
            WHEN CancelationDate2 >= Today THEN CancelationDate2 END AS CancelationDate
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) AS var1(Today)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, FirstPerformancePeriod, ContractLineStartingDate)) AS var2(FirstPerformanceDate)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, FirstPerformanceDate, Today) / FurtherPerformancePeriod) AS var3(CompletedCycles)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, FurtherPerformancePeriod * (CompletedCycles + 1), FirstPerformanceDate)
                  , DATEADD(MONTH, FurtherPerformancePeriod * (CompletedCycles + 2), FirstPerformanceDate)) AS var4(NextPerformanceDate1, NextPerformanceDate2)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -CancelationPeriod, FirstPerformanceDate)
                  , DATEADD(MONTH, -CancelationPeriod, NextPerformanceDate1)
                  , DATEADD(MONTH, -CancelationPeriod, NextPerformanceDate2)) AS var5(CancelationDate0, CancelationDate1, CancelationDate2)
WHERE CancelationDate = '9999-12-31'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad378b00428c21dfaa7eb62e533911c2

Comment: smart! Thanks for your effort an the step-by-step guide to think about the answer, this was very helpful!